# jQuery Progress bar and counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, progress-bar

I searched alot about this and tried some of my own but I can't seem to make it work.
What I'm trying to realize is a progress bar that adds 10 or subtracts 10 every time you press a button.

Example when you press the button UP you add 10 to the progress bar and when you press the button DOWN you remove 10 from the bar.

Whatelse I'd want to realize is a script that can "read" the status of the progressbar and with an if or else function display a text from a paragraph

(If > 50 it'll fadeIn a text, else < 50 it'll fadeIn a different text)
Hope I explained myself well and hope anyone can help me. I'm still new in jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Show your failed approaches. Also, do you want a dependency? e.g. jquery-ui.

Comment: Yeah 10% sorry I'm still new a JavaScript... I can handle CSS and HTML well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has a built-in progress bar that you can do what you want easily.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Here's a simple implementation of what you're trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/makotosan/bW5Wd/3/

Comment: That's what I wanted, but I'd like to have the text/paragraph to display 'seperatly' like instead of pasting a text in a div, to select a <p> with $('p.class') and fade it in. I wanted to have a couple of buttons to add or remove points to the bar, and the very last button to run the 'check' and fadeIn the selected paragraph.

Comment: Modified the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/makotosan/bW5Wd/6/

Is this closer to what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes! That's perfect. Thanks alot ^^
That will do. 
I really need to learn better JavaScript, maybe someone to teach me a bit...

I looked at the coding and understood what it does and why.
I prolly need to learn better all the commands, what they do and/or how to use them, so I'd get better in scripting

Comment: If you're doing web development, definitely should learn JavaScript and utilize frameworks such as jQuery, they are your friend.  If I was helpful, could you +1 my answer?

Comment: I wanted to, but it says that I need 15 reputation to do so witch I don't have... btw is there anyway to 'animate' the progressbar, like instead of instantly going up to have a smooth animation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example to get you started; there are a lot of capabilities to this script, don't be afraid to experiment a little bit:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        #progress {
            position:relative;
            width:25px;
            height:100px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            background-color:#ccc;
        }
        #progress div {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:0;
            width:25px;
            background-color:#f00;
        }
        span {
            margin:10px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            // Define your variables
            var interval=10;
            var half=50;
            var max=100;
            var texts=['Less then 50...','More then 50!'];
            var upButton=$('button[name="up"]');
            var downButton=$('button[name="down"]');
            var bar=$('#progress').find('div');
            upButton.on('click',function(){
                var height=bar.height();
                if(height>=0 && height<max) {
                    var newHeight=parseFloat(height+interval,10);
                    bar.css('height',newHeight);
                    $('span').hide().text((newHeight<half) ? texts[0] : texts[1]).fadeIn();
                }
            });
            downButton.on('click',function(){
                var height=bar.height();
                if(height>0 && height<=max) {
                    var newHeight=parseFloat(height-interval,10);
                    bar.css('height',newHeight);
                    $('span').hide().text((newHeight<half) ? texts[0] : texts[1]).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Progress Bar</h1>
    <p>
        <button name="up">Add</button> <button name="down">Remove</button>
    </p>
    <div id="progress">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, it's very similar to what I had in mind but different also.
What I wanted to do is the jQuery progress bars, the ones witch need an UI to show. The buttons add and remove 10 to the bars.

What I had in mind was a questionary, with different questions and 3-4 answers each. Each answer added or removed 10 points to the jQuery bar, at the last question (witch are the last group of buttons) it ran a script to "check" the bar status, over 50 would fadeIn a paragrath and under 50 would fadeIn a different one.

I wanted to make 3 different bars, at the very last question it would run the "check"